# FastList not generic Java

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, collections

There are things I do not understand concerning the use of `FastList` and I was wondering if someone could help me on that:
Indeed, I have imported the library: `javolution.util.FastList` and I do not get why Eclipse does not accept this program to run (it gives an error for `FastList`):

```
public List<String> invokeMethodList() {
    FastList<String> lMethodList = new FastList<String>();
    lMethodList.add("getAdminLogs");
    return lMethodList;
}
```

Whereas creating another independant project, this code works perfectly fine:

```
import javolution.util.FastList;

public class FastTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            FastList<String> lMethodList = new FastList<String>();
            lMethodList.add("getAdminLogs");
            lMethodList.add("getPlugInsConfig");
            lMethodList.add("reloadPlugIn");
            System.out.println(lMethodList.toString());

      }

}
```

I know this is linked with the fact that FastList is a non generic function but I cannot figure out the difference between those two projects!

I hope someone could give me a hint!

Comment: When you report an error, please report the exception or the compile error

Comment: My guess: The code of the first method is in a class named `FastList` (or at least in a package that *contains* a class named `FastList`).

Comment: Tell us what is the error reported by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first project is configured to use Java version that doesn't support generics (i.e. earlier that 1.5).

Check Java Compiler page in the project Properties.